# jQuery Simple Captcha Plugin

Tags: jquery-plugins

I am using the jQuery SimpleCaptcha plugin - it loads the images fine - but you are unable to click on them. Can anyone give me any hints?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.4.2.min.js'></script> 
    <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.simpleCaptcha-0.2.js'></script> 
    <script type='text/javascript' src='core.js'></script>  
</head>
<body>  
    <form>
      <div id='captcha1'></div>
      <input type='submit' />
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#captcha1').simpleCaptcha({
            numImages: 3,
            introText: '<p>Are yogegeu human? Then pick out the <strong class="captchaText"></strong></p>'
          });
    </script>
    <?php
    if ($_GET['captchaSelection'] == $_SESSION['simpleCaptchaAnswer']) {
      // they're human! (maybe)
    }
    ?>
</body>
```

Many Thanks, 
Joel

Comment: Joel, Sorry for the huge delay, my name is Jordan, author of the plugin. Are you still having problems? I'd like to help and I think the problem might be that you're including "core.js" which is NOT part of the plug in. Feel free to email me if you still need help: jordan aht jkdesign dott org

Comment: Have you checked the class in the css?

Comment: did you add its css in your style file?